# Executando dll via php e laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dll, laravel-5.4

Tenho um projeto em php com laravel e preciso utilizar umas funções contidas em uma dll, tentei utilizar a classe COM(Component Object Model) nativa do PHP, mas o laravel da como classe não encontrada, como posso utilizar essa classe que é nativa do php no laravel ?

Comment: Para início de conversa, a classe que você requer está cadastrada?

Comment: Qual o código usado e que está dando erro???

Comment: Está cadastrada sim, "{310DBDAC-85FF-4008-82A8-E22A09F9460B}". E o erro acontece ao construir a classe COM.

Comment: Tenta adicionar no php.ini a seguinte linha: extension=php_com_dotnet.dll e após isso, reiniciar o serviço.